# Negative look-ahead expression

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

I'm writing a Perl script that performs different actions on hosts depending on which patterns match the FQDN.  I've been struggling to find a regular expression that skips hosts that have the string 'test' in the domain name.

These host names represent the four host name types I'm dealing with:

- node01.prod.com
- node01.test.com
- node02.dmz.prod.com
- node02.dmz.test.com

The following expression *matches* the host name pattern I'm trying to skip:

```
/\w\.test/
```

But, none of the negative look-ahead expressions I've tried will skip the host names with 'test'.  For example, this expression:

```
/\w\.(?!test)/
```

matches/passes all four host name types, including the two that contain the string 'test'.

What's really driving me crazy is that if I hard code part of the host name, the negative look-ahead expression does skip the full host name:

```
/node01\.(?!test)/    # only matches node01.prod.com
```

I'm surely missing something terribly obvious - any suggestions?

Comment: What is wrong with `!/\w\.test/`?

Comment: @TLP, I would like to pass each expression as a variable, so I wanted to avoid using operators outside the /<regex>/ (I'm sure I'm not phrasing that quite right).  I didn't include that detail because I was trying to keep my question short.

Comment: Thanks to all for the helpful answers.  Boy, there really is "more than one way" to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're putting the negative lookahead after your match, which allows it to match a partial node name even if it has the word test in it *somewhere.*

This expression will match any string that doesn't contain `test`:

```
(?!.*test)^.*$
```

---

#### Online demonstration:

> http://regex101.com/r/rZ0vO2

Comment: Ahhh - I did not realize I could 'apply' the negative look ahead to the whole string like that.

Comment: Yep :) Also handy for password validations.

Comment: Given that theinput has no newlines, `/(?!.*test)^.*$/` is just a silly way of saying `/^(?!.*test)/`. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
/\w\.(?!test).+/
```

Your negative lookahead is correct but your regex is not really matching anything after dot.

Comment: that expression still matches on all patterns, including those with the 'test' string.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should do it:

```
/(?:\w+\.(?!test))+\w+/
```

Depending on how you are using the regex, you may also need some anchors to prevent this from matching after `test`:

```
/^(?:\w+\.(?!test))+\w+$/
```

This works by putting the negative lookahead within a repeating group, so that it is checked after each `.` that is matched in your regex.

For example: http://rubular.com/r/TeUYi9EIEL

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this pattern?

```
/(?!.*\.test\.)^.+/
```